# nodemon filters styl file changes

Tags: node.js, npm, stylus, nodemon

I had nodemon wathcing `.styl` files using the following settings in `nodemon.json` without any `ignore` rules:

```
"watch": [
  "src/css/*.styl",
  "src/css/includes/*.styl"
]
```

Any changes were supposed to trigger my build scripts defined in `package.json`.

However after editing a `.styl` file, nodemon seemed to have filtered the changes:

```
Express app running on 3001
[nodemon] files triggering change check: src/css/main.styl
[nodemon] matched rule: **/src/css/*.styl
[nodemon] changes after filters (before/after): 1/0
```

Any ideas about what went wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

add watching extensions in `nodemon.json`:

```
"ext": "js json css styl jade"
```

Comment: I was having the same issue for typescript files. This worked `{
    "verbose": true,
    "watch": ["server/**/*.ts"],
    "ext": "ts js json",
    "ignore": ["server/**/*.spec.ts"],
    "exec": "ts-node index.ts"
}`

Comment: @AdrianMoisa Use `ts,js,json`. No spaces, but commas as delimiter.

Comment: Was having this issue with a Next/React project and needed to add tsx to this